# Laravel PHPSpreadsheet download error

Tags: laravel, phpspreadsheet

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 9 y la librería "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet", lo que deseo hacer es generar un excel pero descargarselo al usuario sin guardarlo, no me interesa que se guarde en el sistema, sólo que el usuario lo pueda descrgar.

He leído por todos lados y he intentado con todas las respuestas pero ninguna me ha funcionado. No sé porque me arroja un error de JSON.

Aclaro por las dudas que estoy trabajando con Livewire aunque esto no tiene nada que ver, ya he probado de generar un archivo y que lo guarde y funciona a la perfección, pero lo que no puedo hacer andar es el download

Hasta llegue a pensar que puede ser que tenga algún problema ya que estoy utilizando debian 11, pero no creo

Les dejo el código y el error que me arroja

Muchas gracias por adelantado!

P/D: Ya probé con ob_end_clean(); pero no funcionó
La sección de los headers lo saqué de la documentación oficial
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#redirect-output-to-a-clients-web-browser

Bueno ahora sí les pongo el código

```
public function exportExcel2()
    {
        $users = $this->getUsers();
        $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
        $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
        $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'LISTADO DE USUARIOS DEL SISTEMA DE GESTIÓN DE MORA');
        $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
        header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="myfile.xlsx"');
        header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
        $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
        ob_end_clean();
        $writer->save('php://output');
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

porque no intentas guardando el archivo en el storage temporalmente y lo descargas, así no tienes que agregar los headers, así he trabajado y no  ha presentado ningún problema.

```
$path = "tmp/{$file_name}.xlsx";

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

$writer->save(storage_path("app/{$path}"));

return Storage::download($path, "file_to_download.xlsx");
```

Comment: Genial! Muchas gracias skidrunk77 funcionó tu solución. Gracias!